# Cannot overwrite a file on an SMB network share After upgrading to OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, smb

Last week I upgraded to Yosemite and I work a lot with saving files to a network share, mainly updating existing templates. Usually I just copy the newest template to the network share and it asks if I want to Overwrite/replace. Now when I attempt that it never asks me if I want to overwrite. It just hangs. Then if I attempt to change the file on my desktop, like rename, I get the error -8076. To resolve that error I have to run killall Finder for it to release the file.

I am however able to delete the file and then copy up the new one but when working with 40-50 new files a day that is a burden especially with large files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to the drive with CIFS:\ instead of SMB:\. I have had the same issue and when trying it with the CIFS protocol it worked.

Comment: I have similar [problem](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177505/unable-to-overwrite-some-file-formats-via-share-drive); changing to CIFS protocol does not work (problem persists)

Comment: Additional information: Yosemite uses SMB3 as default mounting protocol, while Mavericks use SMB2. And CIFS is SMB1.